# Filtering data with from statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So let's say I have this table with these rows in it

Table name: MYTABLE

```
ID | NUMBER | FK_ID
1  | 0      | 26
2  | 0      | 26
3  | 1      | 26
4  | 0      | 27
5  | 1      | 27
```

Now I want to filter out only the rows that that go under the same FK_ID and have two or more NUMBER 0's in them.

So for instance if I would apply this filter here, I would only see one row which corresponds to the FK_ID 26 because it has two NUMBER 0s in it's MYTABLE data.

Is this even possible to do or should I just handle the whole data in my programming language not filter it like that from DB.

Comment: Why would you only see one row for FK 26 - and which one, ID 1, 2 or 3? Or do you *only* want to get back the `FK_ID`, not the whole row(s)? I'm not sure if your filter is to remove all zeros which are duplicates, or only include those which are duplicates.

Comment: Select fk_id from table group by fk_id having count(decode(number,0,1))>=2

Comment: Well say FK_ID 26 is one basket of tomatoes, it has not ready tomatoes in it(0) and one ready tomatoe(1).  Now I just want to filter our all the baskets that have 2 or more not ready tomatoes in it.

Comment: Yes, I understand the concept of filtering, but what you've said is (still) ambiguous to me. You said you want one row for FK_ID 26. Do you only want to see the FK; or the ID(s) as well? Do you want to see anything for FK 27? It would help if you included the actual result set you want back.

Comment: Well I have everything else covered in my SQL statement allready. All the data that I want from that row and so on. I just needed the filtering help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this query work for you?

```
SELECT 
    FK_ID
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE NUMBER = 0
GROUP BY FK_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Also, consider renaming the NUMBER column, as NUMBER is a [reserved word in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm).

Comment: Yes, I just made an example column here but I guess it was not named that well indeed. Trying this solution out right now.

Comment: Here how would you count that number col have 2 or mnore 0's for a particular FK_ID. You havn't mention any cond. for that.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai `WHERE NUMBER = 0` limits the rows to only those that are 0's. `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2` limits the FK_ID's to those that have at least 2 rows that have NUMBER=0. Check out Code Listing 14 at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-jan/o13sql-1886636.html

Comment: Sorry. that was my bad. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT FK_ID , 
COUNT(DECODE(NUMBER ,0,1)) 
FROM TEST_DATA 
GROUP BY FK_ID 
HAVING COUNT(DECODE(NUMBER ,0,1)) >= 2
```

Fiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44d70/4